# Fixed nav menu doesn't work in IE 11 or Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position

This bit works fine in Chrome, but the links don't work in IE or Edge unless I turn off `position: fixed.` Anyone have any ideas? I've searched for all kinds of similarly-worded questions, and nothing has proved helpful. Not sure why having `position: fixed` disables any interactivity in IE.

```
<style>
    .act-nav {
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      top: 273px;
      width: 230px;
      background-color: #000;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .act-nav a {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px;
      width: 210px;
    }
  </style>
<div>
  <div class="act-nav">
    <a class="act-button-yellow act-button" href="#map">Map</a>
    <a class="act-button-yellow act-button" href="#stations">Stations</a>
    <a class="act-button-yellow act-button" href="#talks">Talks</a>
    <a class="act-button-yellow act-button" href="#reqs">Open Reqs</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you try adding a `z-index` to the fixed nav?

Comment: Yeah, 0, 99. Didn't help

Comment: there is no need to nest a fixed div inside a static or relative div. You should place navigation widgets (lists in grouping elements) as childs of the body. eg.<body><div role="main">content</div><div role="navigation" style="position:fixed">site/page navigation links</div>. Experiment with your layout by using inline style rules and the DOM explorer of the dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div role="main" style="min-height:1000px;max-width:10em;margin:1em auto;background:red">this is the main content</div>
    
    <ul role="navigation" style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;height:100%;width:10em;background:orange">
    <a><li>menu item</li></a>
    <a><li>menu item</li></a>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Unfortunately this is in a wished and I don't have control over the main content.